# webdriverio appium browser lauch on iOS device error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am getting following error when tried to launch safari browser on ios device using webdriver.io and appium.

> ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Could not initialize ios-deploy make sure it
>   is installed (npm install -g ios-deploy) and works on your system

Answer (score 1):

If you are running appium on a real iOS device, there are some other dependencies you will need to install.

specifically, you need to install `ios-deploy`.

You can install it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

`brew install ios-deploy`

Setting up appium for real iOS devices involves a bunch more tricky steps you may need to solve after this one. Here is a tutorial I wrote just two weeks ago, so is probably the most up to date source right now:

https://appiumpro.com/editions/40